# Python-Remove rows based on lack of character

Tags: python

I would like to remove a row from my file if it contains a letter other than A, C, G, or T.  So that ['TC', 'CY', 'GS', 'GA', 'CT'] will become ['TC', 'GA', 'CT'].

The files will have an unknown number of rows and will contain patterns of 2 or more letters in any order.  In addition, I do not know the other letters that are present (Y or S or something else).

How would I go about setting up a program for this preferably in Python?  I already can import my file and read the rows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve it with a simple regular expression and a list comprehension.

```
>>> import re
>>> data = ['TC', 'CY', 'GS', 'GA', 'CT']
>>> [x for x in data if re.match(r'^[ACGT]+$', x)]
['TC', 'GA', 'CT']
```

Comment: You could even do it with just the regex '[^ACGT]': if *not* re.match(r'[^ACGT]')

Comment: @Dave: That doesn't work. It returns all items from `data`, because all strings begin with A, C, G or T.

Comment: What I'm actually saying here is give me a match if the string does NOT match A, C, G, or T.  (The ^ works differently inside brackets).

Comment: I understand your intention, and I understand regex syntax, but re.match('foo', 'foobar') will return a match object, while re.match('foo', 'barfoo') won't. So your solution will not always work, only if a string doesn't *start* with A, C, G or T.

Comment: Dave's solution will work fine with `re.search` instead of `re.match`.

Comment: @F.J Ah i see where we're having a communication breakdown : ) I always forget which one is which.  Of course then you don't need the caret in the answer above anyways, right?

Answer (score 3):

How about this, as a one liner:

```
valid = [l.strip() for l in fh if all(c in 'ACGT' for c in l.strip())]
```

where fh is your file handle.

Comment: consider: `all(c in 'ACGT' for c in l.strip())`, which will avoid creating two lists at each iteration; the outer list comprehension isn't neccesary, `all()` will happily iterate over a generator expression, and the list containing the bases could be a constant; in this case a string literal will do.

Answer (score 0):

A little slow one-liner because of type casting(you can decrease it by assigning set("ACGT") before), but a small one:

```
>>> l
['TC', 'CY', 'GS', 'GA', 'CT']
>>> [i for i in l if not set(i) - set("ACGT")]
['TC', 'GA', 'CT']
```